# Querying for a subsequence using Django ArrayFields

Tags: django, postgresql, sequence, subsequence

I have an ArrayField that stores sequences of integers in it, for example: `Sequences.objects.first().seq` returns `[5,4,4,3,2,2,1]`. The sequences are always stored in decreasing order, and I want to filter `Sequences` to find a subsequence. However, I'm running into problems when trying to find a subsequence that contains repeated elements and I don't know how to go about solving this problem.

For instance, if I wish to filter for any sequence containing the subsequence `q = [5,4,4,4,2]`, I would try `Sequences.objects.filter(seq__contains=q)`, but this QuerySet will include the sequence `[5,4,4,3,2,2,1]`, since each element of q is individually in the sequence, but not all together. However, I do not want only exact matches. If I filtered by q, I would like to include something like `[6,5,5,4,4,4,3,2,1]` but reject something like `[5,4,4,3,2,2,1]` since the former case has all of q with multiplicity, and the latter is missing a 4, and so doesnt contain q as a subsequence.

Comment: Did you try using `iexact`? i.e. `Sequences.objecst.filter(seq__iexact=q)`

Comment: Thanks for asking! I don't want to use `iexact` and have clarified the question some.